# Karma ignores angular http get request

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

I am using Karma to test a function within an angular directive.  The function executes fine but the `http.get` request in it seems to be ignored where as others throw an `unexpected get` error.

```
beforeEach(inject(function($injector, $compile, $rootScope){
    $gCompile = $compile;
    $gScope = $rootScope;
    $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
    $gHttp = $httpBackend;
}));

it("Should login to the UI", function() {

    //Compile directive
    var element = angular.element('<my-app></my-app>');
    $gCompile(element)($gScope);

    //Reference it's local scope
    var dirScope = element.scope();

    $gScope.$digest();
    dirScope.login();
});
```

The get request is in the login function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might help if you can show us what the `login()` function looks like, but for now it looks like you're not using `$httpBackend` correctly.

Take a look at [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/%24httpBackend).

You should set up an expectation on `$httpBackend`, then call your `login()` function, then call `flush()` on `$httpBackend`.